# how to use image in email template in dynamics crm 2013?

Tags: image, dynamics-crm-2011, email-templates, dynamics-crm-2013

I've to insert an image in email template. I've copy paste the image, didn't work for me. Now I've the same image at a url in my web resource can we use that url to use the image from a url?

Thank You

Comment: if the image is a web resource it will require an active crm session to see it. Locate it outside of crm if you want non-crm users to be able to access it or you want anybody to access it without an active crm session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the only way by which you can use Images inside of an Email is to host those images on a public URL and link it in the email body.

On a side note, you can also try referencing the image in an email attachment (though am sure it will work or not).